# Can cooling airflow be too fast for efficiency?

Tags: air, cooling

If using pressurized air flow to cool a hot metal tube (by blowing the air through the tube, not blowing it over the exterior), would high volume fast airflow cool better than low volume slower air flow?  Can air flow be too fast for efficient heat transfer from the metal?

Comment: I suspect that there *might* be a problem at high air flow rates due to turbulent vortices near the surface of the object, reducing air exchange.  But non-laminar fluid flow is a very messy topic, so it's impossible to generalize to any significant degree.

Comment: Do you need to use air to cool a hot metal tube?  Air is a poor conductor of heat and it has a low specific heat capacity.  Water cooling would be much more efficient if your application can tolerate it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the extreme case, where the gas moves extremely slowly, it is obvious that it carries away minimum heat, so its cooling effect is small - only the heat necessary to heat the little amount of gas inside the pipe is removed and after that happens, the heat removed per second is close to zero.

Now, increase the gas mass flow rate (mass current) - in practice, by opening the valve on the gas reservoir more. For small rates, the gas will move slowly enough to still achieve almost the same temperature as the hot body, but since it moves away quicker, more heat is removed from the hot body per second.

One cannot extrapolate this to arbitrary high flow rates... because when the gas moves very fast, any gas element is in contact with the body for too short a time and it is not able to acquire as much heat as when it moves slowly. Thus there will be some critical mass rate beyond which the cooling power decreases.

For extremely fast gas flow, the gas will even heat up the hot body via friction. This is a concern in aviation, very fast-moving plane will be heated by friction from the atmosphere, so the airframe must be specially designed to withstand much greater temperatures, especially if its is for supersonic flight.

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, speeding up the airflow will only *increase* the rate of heat transfer, because faster airflow means 1) a thinner boundary layer across which the heat has to be moved and 2) faster removal of the heat thus taken up from the tube into the air.